# Accept only authentificated requests to backend

Tags: django, authentication, backend, auth0

I have this question. I am quite new in this area.
I have web app.
This consist of services deployed on Docker engine.
The main services/containers are:

- Frontend : React on Nginx web server
- Backend (API) : Django, DRF on gunicorn on Nginx

For frontend I use Auth0 provider. It works as expected. If user is not authenticated/authorized it is redirected to login page.

Now I want also to "secure" my backend that it only would accept authenticated connections from frontend.
For backend (Django) I also have CORS enabled (*django-cors-headers* package), but I still can connect from my browser my-site/api/ and get the response.
Does anybody know which strategy should I use.
Should I somehow secure it using JWT tokens. Somehow pass it to backend in my request?

Comment: check this out https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/ . You can use basic authentication, token authentication , session authentication, and many others

Answer (score 0):

There is various ways of authorizing API calls from your front-end applications to execute actions on your back-end. These will tend to vary in a few aspects:

- Complexity
- Needing to know who sent the request
- Access surfaces
- Duration of access
- Roles
- and so on...

In this case if you have authenticated users on your front-end using AuthO then a JWT could make sense since using this method you can encode specific user data that will allow you to make the decision on your backend as to if that user should have access to that action at that time.

Here is an [article](https://blog.restcase.com/4-most-used-rest-api-authentication-methods/) explaining a few popular methods of authentication